# Ordenar ArrayList Json por valor de una clave

Tags: java, json, arraylist

He estado buscando y me gustaría ordenar el siguiente ArrayList que almacena objetos Json:

```html
[
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "category_id": 1,
    "serie": false,
    "img_online": "/ticketresource/img/deportes/fefe7zduv5t/200728145853.png",
    "serie_online": false,
    "dates": [
      {
        "date": "2020-08-02",
        "time": "00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "event_id": 3,
    "category_id": 1,
    "serie": false,
    "img_online": "/ticketresource/img/deportes/fefe7zduv5t/200728145723.png",
    "serie_online": false,
    "dates": [
      {
        "date": "2020-07-31",
        "time": "08:00"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-08-01",
        "time": "23:30"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Necesito que se ordenen por la primera fecha de cada evento, en este ejemplo el evento con event_id 3 debería estar en la primera posición, ya que la primera fecha que tiene(2020-07-31), es primero que la del evento_id 2(2020-08-02).

Este json se encuentra en un `List<Json> todosEventos = new ArrayList<Json>();`

que almacena objetos del tipo:`Json eventosData = Json.object();`

Agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: Hola Valeria, buen dia. que libreria de JSON estas usando para JAVA. org.json.* ?

Comment: Hola, sí, esa es la que estoy usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca te envio una clase que implementa Comparator para objetos de tipo org.json

```
public class SortJSON implements Comparator<org.json.JSONObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(org.json.JSONObject e1, org.json.JSONObject e2) {
        try {
            JSONArray arr1 = (e1.has("dates")) ? e1.getJSONArray("dates") : null;
            JSONArray arr2 = (e2.has("dates")) ? e2.getJSONArray("dates") : null;
            if (arr1 == null || arr2 == null || arr1.length() == 0 || arr2.length() == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            String date1 = arr1.getJSONObject(0).getString("date") + arr1.getJSONObject(0).getString("time");
            String date2 = arr2.getJSONObject(0).getString("date") + arr2.getJSONObject(0).getString("time");

            Long d1 = Long.parseLong(date1.replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(":", ""), 10);
            Long d2 = Long.parseLong(date2.replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(":", ""), 10);
            return d1.compareTo(d2);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Aca pasas la Lista o array.

```
SortJSON s = new SortJSON();
//todosEventos seria tu array json
Collections.sort(todosEventos, s);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me funcionó perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un arraylist, podes llamar a Collections.sort y ordenar usando comparable o comparator. Desconozco la estructura de tu proyecto, pero te dejo un ejemplo usando un ejemplo básico:

hace de cuenta que tenes la clase empleado, con todos sus atributos, Getters, Setters, ToString y constructores. Ahora necesitas comparar los empleados por su sueldo de la siguiente manera

```
public class Empleado implements Comparable<Empleado>{
@Override
    public int compareTo(Empleado e){
        if(e.getSalario()>salario){
            return -1;
        }else if(e.getSalario()>salario){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
}
```

luego debes ordenar usando

```
Collections.sort(empleados);
```

la otra forma usando comparator, tenes que crear una clase vacía cualquiera que implemente comparator de la siguiente manera:

```
public class CompararEmpleados implements Comparator<Empleado>{
     
     @Override
     public int compare(Empleado e1, Empleado e2){
        if(e1.getEdad()>e2.getEdad()){
            return -1;
        }else if(e1.getEdad()>e2.getEdad()){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

y ordenarlos:

```
Collections.sort(empleados,new CompararEmpleados());
```

Si estas trabajando con JavaScript, los podes ordenar mas facil y después usarlos ya ordenados.